# how to cut audio file and merge with video file in android?

Tags: android, audio, video, ffmpeg

I want to cut audio and merge an audio file with video programmatically in android.

I don't know how to work with [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) , can anyone tell me how to start with or another solution?

Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

Use mp4parser library

library
https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser

test
https://github.com/vicmns/mp4parser-android-test

Comment: :- which library use ? in this library many libraries like iso parser, muxer , which library add this test code?

Comment: @NiravRanpara i also use mp4parser but its not working its give me an error will you please help me out to solve that specific problem thanks in advance. i use this library 
com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.0.5.4